# Arithmetic operations between variables

Tags: php

I'm beginner with `php`. I am trying to apply some random arithmetic operation between two variables

```
$operators = array(
    "+",
    "-",
    "*",
    "/"
    );

$num1 = 10;
$num2 = 5;

$result = $num1 . $operators[array_rand($operators)] . $num2;

echo $result;
```

it prints values like these

```
10+5
10-5
```

How can I edit my code in order to do this arithmetic operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you could use `eval()` to do this, it relies on the variables being safe.

This is much, *much* safer:

```
function compute($num1, $operator, $num2) {
    switch($operator) {
        case "+": return $num1 + $num2;
        case "-": return $num1 - $num2;
        case "*": return $num1 * $num2;
        case "/": return $num1 / $num2;

        // you can define more operators here, and they don't
        // have to keep to PHP syntax. For instance:
        case "^": return pow($num1, $num2);

        // and handle errors:
        default: throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid operator");
    }
}
```

Now you can call:

```
echo compute($num1, $operators[array_rand($operators)], $num2);
```

Comment: Also realized my answer didn't need the `break;` because `return` would prevent the rest of the switch from executing anyways. +1

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you!

You can use this function:

```
function calculate_string( $mathString )    {
    $mathString = trim($mathString);     // trim white spaces
    $mathString = preg_replace ('[^0-9\+-\*\/\(\) ]', '', $mathString);    // remove any non-numbers chars; exception for math operators

    $compute = create_function("", "return (" . $mathString . ");" );
    return 0 + $compute();
}

//As an example
echo calculate_string("10+5");
```

Output:

```
15
```

So in your case you can do this:

```
$operators = array(
    "+",
    "-",
    "*",
    "/"
    );

$num1 = 10;
$num2 = 5;

echo calculate_string($num1 . $operators[array_rand($operators)] . $num2);
```

Comment: From [PHP docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) `This function internally performs an eval() and as such has the same security issues as eval(). Additionally it has bad performance and memory usage characteristics.`.

Comment: Urrghh... `create_function`